# Getting error while inserting data to MySQL using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

**HI I am developing a project in eclipse using Hibernate. I found this  Error in my hibernate.cfg.xml file**

Please help with this problem.

I have included all the necessary libraries.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>



        <!-- Related to the connection START -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.user">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">93Pb3gaNv0</property>
        <!-- Related to the connection END -->

        <!-- Related to hibernate properties START -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dailet">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update </property>
        <!-- Related to hibernate properties END -->

        <!-- Related to mapping START -->
        <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>
        <!-- Related to mapping END -->




    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

user.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

```
      <hibernate-mapping>
      <class name="mypack.DataProvider" table="user_info">
      <id name="user_id" column="id">
      <generator class="assinged"></generator>
      </id>
      <property name="user_name" column="name"></property>
       <property name="user_address" column="address"></property>
      </class>
      </hibernate-mapping>
```

DataProvider.java

```
 package mypack;

public class DataProvider {

private int user_id;
public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}
public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}
public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}
public String getUser_address() {
    return user_address;
}
public void setUser_address(String user_address) {
    this.user_address = user_address;
}
private String user_name;
private String user_address;
}
```

DataInsertion.java

```
package mypack;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DataInsertion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DataInsertion().insertInfo();

}

public void insertInfo()
{
Configuration con = new Configuration();
con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory SF = con.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = SF.openSession();
DataProvider provider = new DataProvider();
provider.setUser_id(121);
provider.setUser_name("Mehandi Hassan");
provider.setUser_address("Delhi");
Transaction TR = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(provider);
System.out.println("Object save successfully");
TR.commit();
session.close();
SF.close(); 
}
}
```

Error:

```
May 29, 2015 5:34:46 PM                   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
 INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
 May 29, 2015 5:34:46 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
 May 29, 2015 5:34:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 29, 2015 5:34:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 29, 2015 5:34:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
May 29, 2015 5:34:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration        
getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid    
configuration
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)
at mypack.DataInsertion.insertInfo(DataInsertion.java:18)
at mypack.DataInsertion.main(DataInsertion.java:11)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 25;    
Document is invalid: no grammar found.
at 


   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.
    createSAXParseExcepti       on    (Unknown Source)
   at   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.
    ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.      
   XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.    
   impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
   impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
    impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
    impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.  
   scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.
   XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
   impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
   impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
     impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.

    impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.
     scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.
  internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
   parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
    parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.
    parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.
  internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
  ... 3 more
```

Comment: Did you close tag `<hibernate-configuration>`?

Comment: is there a reason, that you are using xml-configs instead of annotations ?

Comment: yes bro i have close the hibernate-configration file

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate DataProvider with @Entity and the id with @Id

@Entity
public class DataProvider {
   @Id
   private int user_id;
   @Column
   private String user_name;
   @Column
   private String user_address;

... setters getters
}

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate 4.x you should use the same DTD 
you need to add in config file hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>

        <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.user">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">93Pb3gaNv0</property>

        ....
        ....

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```